# Mako for python

Tags: python, mako

I am a newbie for mako and want to create .py scripts programatically from a template .py script. So does something like this work

Lets say my template script has a variable `var1 = ${var1}`, that takes say integer values. I want to be able to create many copies with particular values of `var1` variable. How I create a caller that declares `var1` as a list, say `var1 = [1,2,3,4]` and iterate over the values and pass them to the template. How does one do this, does something like `render(**locals())` work?

Also I am unable to download Mako, is there a windows python 2.7 download available?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a template object, you can just iterate over the values you need and use the `render` method to obtain the new output as follows:

```
from mako.template import Template

template = Template('var1 = ${var1}')

for v in range(1, 5):
    context = {'var1': v}
    print template.render(**context)
```

Example output:

```
var1 = 1
var1 = 2
var1 = 3
var1 = 4
```

Regarding the idea of using `locals()`, that would certainly work:

```
for var1 in range(1, 5):
    print template.render(**locals())
```

Anyway, I prefer to explicitly create the context dictionary. This is consistent with the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) whith states that explicit is better than implicit.

Finally, with regard to the installation problem, I don't know of any binary available, but you can install using `pip` as explained in the [mako download page](http://www.makotemplates.org/download.html).

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate on what context and ** context does

Comment: Also what gets passed in when I say **locals, is it all the variables in the current local scope, so if I run this out of a script, all the vars defined in the script basically? Many thanks.

Comment: When you use `**context`, the dictionary pairs are expanded as if the method were called like `template.render(var1=v)`. For more information, please have a look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/183066).

Comment: When you use `locals` all the variables in the [local symbol table](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) are passed. In the example above, is something like: `{'var1': 4, 'template': <mako.template.Template object at 0x7fb5870860d0>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, 'Template': <class 'mako.template.Template'>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}`. Despite this works, I don't really like it because you're passing more variables than needed to the template.